# how to retrieve the value from grid cell in GXT

Tags: eclipse, gxt

I have created a editable grid with only 3 of its columns out of 5 as editable. I'm not getting how to retrieve values from the particular cells, so that the values can be dynamically added and displayed inside another cell of same grid. I've tried this code in eclipse galileo. But its not working. Please help me.

```
package org.openxdata.analyzer.client;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.grid.ColumnConfig;  
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Element;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.grid.ColumnModel;  
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.Style.HorizontalAlignment;  
import java.util.List;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.store.ListStore;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.MessageBox;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.Window;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.button.Button;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.TextField;  
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.grid.CellEditor;  
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.grid.EditorGrid;  
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.layout.FitLayout;  
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.layout.FormData;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.BaseModel;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.event.ButtonEvent;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.event.SelectionListener;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.Viewport;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.NumberField;


public class Grid1 extends Viewport {

    @Override
    protected void onRender(Element parent, int index) {
        super.onRender(parent, index);
        setStyleAttribute("margin", "10px");



        final Window w = new Window();
        w.setHeading("grids");
        w.setSize(600,250);
        w.setModal(true);
        //w.setLayout(new RowLayout(Orientation.VERTICAL)); 
        w.setLayout(new FitLayout());
        w.setResizable(false);

        FormData formData = new FormData("98%");


        List<ColumnConfig> col = new ArrayList<ColumnConfig>();
        ColumnConfig column = new ColumnConfig();
        column.setId("disease");
        column.setWidth(150);
        TextField<String> text = new TextField<String>();    
        text.setAllowBlank(false);    
        text.setAutoValidate(true);    
        //column.setEditor(new CellEditor(text));  
        col.add(column);


        column = new ColumnConfig();
        column.setId("exposure");
        column.setWidth(120);
        TextField<String> text1 = new TextField<String>();    
        text1.setAllowBlank(false);    
        text1.setAutoValidate(true);    
        //column.setEditor(new CellEditor(text1));  
        col.add(column);

        column = new ColumnConfig();
        column.setId("plus");
        column.setHeader("Exposure");
        column.setWidth(80);
    final NumberField text2 = new NumberField();    
        text2.setAllowBlank(false);    
        text2.setAutoValidate(true);    
        column.setEditor(new CellEditor(text2));  
        col.add(column);

        column = new ColumnConfig();
        column.setId("minus");
        column.setHeader("Exposure");
        column.setWidth(80);
        final NumberField text3 = new NumberField();   
        text3.setAllowBlank(false);    
        text3.setAutoValidate(true);    
        column.setEditor(new CellEditor(text3));  
        col.add(column);

        column = new ColumnConfig();
        column.setId("total");
        column.setHeader("Totals");
        column.setWidth(80);
        final NumberField text4 = new NumberField();      
        text4.setAllowBlank(false);    
        text4.setAutoValidate(true);    
        column.setEditor(new CellEditor(text4));  
        column.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
        col.add(column);
        //ColumnModel cm = new ColumnModel(col);

        ListStore<Grid2> employeeList = new ListStore<Grid2>();    
        employeeList.add(cool.getgrid());


        ColumnModel cm = new ColumnModel(col);  


        final EditorGrid<Grid2> grid = new EditorGrid<Grid2>(employeeList, cm);  
        //grid.setStyleAttribute("borderTop", "none");  
        //grid.setAutoExpandColumn("name");  
        grid.setBorders(true);  
        grid.setStripeRows(true);  
          Button calculate = new Button("Calculate");
            w.addButton(calculate);



            calculate.addSelectionListener( new SelectionListener<ButtonEvent>()

                    {


                 @Override  
                    public void componentSelected(ButtonEvent ce) {  
                    {   

                        Double   p=(Double)text2.getValue();
                        Double m=(Double)text3.getValue();


                        Double t=p+m;

                        text4.setValue(t);

                        }  
                 }

                    });



        w.add(grid);
        w.show();
    }
}


class Grid2 extends BaseModel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Grid2(){
    }
    public Grid2  ( String  dis, String exp, Integer x,Integer y) {
        set("disease", dis);
        set("exposure", exp);
        set("plus", x);
        set("minus", y);
    }

    public Grid2 (String  dis, String exp, Integer x,
            Integer y, Double v) {
        // this(dis, exp, x,y,v);
        set("disease", dis);
        set("exposure", exp);
        set("plus", x);
        set("minus", y);
        set("total", v);
    }
    public Grid2(String a,String b,String c,String d,String t){
        set("disease",a);
        set("exposure",b);
        set("plus",c);
        set("minus",d);
        set("total",t);
    }
    public  Integer getplus() {
        return (Integer)get("plus");
    }
    public Integer getminus() {
        return (Integer)get("minus");
    }


    public class TestData {  

        public  List<Grid2> getData()  
        {  
            List<Grid2> lt= new ArrayList<Grid2>();  



            lt.add(new Grid2("Christina Blake","Information Technology",1,2,1.23));  
            lt.add(new Grid2("Heriberto Rush","Information Technology",3,4,1.334));  

            return lt;  
        }  
    }  

}

class cool {  

    public static  List<Grid2> getgrid()  
    {  
        List<Grid2> data = new ArrayList<Grid2>();  

        //data.add(new Grid(" "," ","Exposure"," ","Totals"));  
        data.add(new Grid2(" "," ","(+)","(-)"," "));  
        data.add(new Grid2("'Disease'","(+)",0,0,0.00));  
        data.add(new Grid2(" ","(-)",0,0,0.00));  
        data.add(new Grid2("Totals"," ",0,0,0.00));  


        return data;  
    }  

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are modifying any editable cell, then u can get `store.getModifiedRecords()`. It will give u the modified records. This record can give u the changes done to a record. I think `record.getChanges()` method is there which will return u the map for that model(record). At that time each model represents a `row.u` can get the cell number which is modified as a key and the value corresponding to it.

After that u can do `store.removeAll()`. Then add the previous data plus the new data which has to be binded with respective columconfig.

Then call `store.add(List of models containing whole data)`.
Then `grid.recalculate();`

Answer (score 1):

Add a StoreListener to the ListStore behind the grid. Handle the update event and you're set

Comment: thanks for the reply.                                                 i dint get how to do it,can you please send me the code snippet ...

Answer (score 1):

This will help you. I'm getting value by this:

```
GridCellRenderer<Grid2> checkStatus = new GridCellRenderer<Grid2>() {
    public Object render(Grid2 model, String property,
            ColumnData config, int rowIndex, int colIndex,
            ListStore<Grid2> store, Grid<Grid2> grid) {
        int val = model.get(property);
        return val;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for gxt 2.x.
`store.getModifiedRecords().get(0).getChanges()` - returns Map with field name as key and old cell value as value of map.
`store.getModifiedRecords().get(0).get("field_name")` returns new value as String